# Create and restore specific objects

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2012, database-backups, database-restore

I'm using microsoft sql-server 2012 for my application. I use "create and restore" backup commands but when I restore backup, all objects will be restored such as stored procedures. How can I create backup and restore it only for specific objects of my database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.  You could restore the backup with a different database name, then copy the required objects across to the live DB.

A better approach would be to keep you progammables in a change control system.  Then you would be able to retrieve any version of any object whenever you need.